# Visual Studio Assembly - I dont get why my assembly code gives me this values

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86-64, masm

Sorry for my bad english
Im new on assembly programing.
im getting somre problems with some assembly code in Visual Studio.

```
mov rbx,rcx
mov rsi,rdx 

xor rcx,rcx
xor rdi,rdi


m:      
mov rax,[rbx+rcx]
mov rdi,[rsi+0]
mul rdi
mov [r8+0],rax

mov rax,[rbx+rcx]
mov rdi,[rsi+4]
mul rdi
mov [r8+4],rax

mov rax,[rbx+rcx]
mov rdi,[rsi+8]
mul rdi
mov [r8+8],rax

mov rax,[rbx+rcx]
mov rdi,[rsi+12]
mul rdi
mov [r8+12],rax

cmp rcx,12
jle cruz

    cruz:
mov rax,[r8+0]
mov [r9+rcx],rax

mov rax,[r8+4]
mov [r9+16+rcx],rax

mov rax,[r8+8]
mov [r9+32+rcx],rax

mov rax,[r8+12]
mov [r9+48+rcx],rax

add rcx,4 

cmp rcx,12
jle m
```

- RCX has this array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
- RDX has `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
- r8  has `[0, 0, 0, 0]`
- r9  has `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

this code *should* give this:

```
array in r9 --> [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 6, 9, 12, 4, 8, 12, 16]
```

But instead it gives me this:

```
array in r9 --> [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 4, 6, 8, 12, 6, 9, 12, 16, 8, 12, 16]
```

Something happens when im moving the first elements from the array, and i dont know what it is, please help me.

i  dont know if im doing the things right, i really need help to know what im doing wrong.

Comment: Are your array elements 4 bytes or 8 bytes? You’re using 8-byte operations, but only offsetting the address by 4 bytes for each element.

Comment: Your `jle cruz; cruz:` sequence looks suspicious.

Comment: Yup, a conditional branch that goes to the same place for fall-through and taken is a NOP, and almost certainly not what you want.